# How to use asterisk emoji with Sphinx and without warnings?

Tags: python-sphinx

If I use an asterisk emoji character in my documentation (*️⃣) then Sphinx will complain with a warning:

```
WARNING: Inline emphasis start-string without end-string.
```

That is because it is interpreting the character as a separate asterisk plus something else.

How could avoid that warning?

I am trying to avoid having to use literal/:samp:, since they add a grey background to the character in the HTML output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape any reserved reStructuredText markup character with a backslash:

```
\*️⃣
```